# Simple Java concurrency question

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

Thread 1:

```
if(!conditionFullfiled) this.wait();
```

Thread 2:

```
if(conditionFullfiled) thread1.notify();
```

I want to wake up thread 1 from thread 2, when some condition is fullfiled. But isn't there a problem, when `thread1.notify()` is called `if(!conditionFullfiled) ***HERE*** this.wait();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do `obj.wait()` and `obj.notify()`, you need to own the monitor of the object you're going to wait/notify on. In your code, you probably don't want thread1.notify(). Example:

```
   Object someSharedObject = ...
```

Thread1:

```
   synchronized(someSharedObject) {
     // while NOT if for spurious wake ups.
     while(!conditionFullfiled) someSharedObject.wait();
   }
```

Thread2:

```
   synchronized(someSharedObject) {
     if(conditionFullfiled) someSharedObject.notify(); // this wakes thread1
   }
```

The `synchronized` lock is on `someSharedObject` (can be `this`), which means the two threads will never clash. `.wait()` releases the currently held monitor, so Thread2 will not be blocked when Thread1 is waiting.

**Edit:** I learnt something about spurious wake ups. The `.wait()` must be done in a `while` loop - `if` is not enough. [Why do threads spontaneously awake from wait()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540984/why-do-threads-spontaneously-awake-from-wait) . Thanks Enno Shioji for teaching me.

**Edit:** Clarified `.wait()` releases monitor.

Comment: `if` should be replaced by `while` to cope with spurious wake ups.

Comment: `someSharedObject.wait();` is called inside the synchronized block - doesn't that mean that Thread2 won't never enter into the other synchronized block, if Thread1 is already waiting?

Comment: @fhucho, `wait()` releases the currently held monitors.

Comment: @Martin: "there really isn't anything that wake a thread up randomly" According to the spec, there is... I think the API doc of `wait()` should warn this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540984/why-do-threads-spontaneously-awake-from-wait

Comment: @Martin Algesten thanks, will you please also add a mention about the fact that wait() releases all monitors?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 problems here.

1. you should not call wait() and notify() on thread object itself. Better way to do this is to use special lock object, e.g.

   private Object lock = new Object();
   ......
   lock.wait();
2. The next problem is that you have to call both wait() and notify into synchornized block, i.e.

   syncronized(lock) {
       // some code
       lock.wait();
   }

then in other place in code say:

```
syncronized(lock) {
    lock.notify(); // this line will cause the wait to terminate and the first thread to continue.
}
```

It is convenient to localize both `wait()` and `notify()` wrapping methods in one class, so they have access to lock object.

For more information read 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score 0):

What object you use as "this"? If you invoke wait() on thread1 object, and both statements you have shown are wrapped in a loop like this:

> ```
> new Runnable() {
>     synchronized (thread1) {
>         thread1.wait() 
>     }
> }
> ```

Then your code will work as you want. (First thread will halt when condition is false, and work otherwise).
The trick is that interactions on the thread object are synchronized, so one thread can not interrupt while other is working with the object.

EDIT:
It will be even better if you will synchronize not on the thread, but on some other object (you can simply create pure object to provide locks).

Answer (score 0):

No problem at all since wait releases object lock (in case this).

It's a best practice to guard wait/notify conditions in while blocks - to avoid spurious  wake-ups.