# Would Linux Timer be triggered before the expire time?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, timer

Our game have to do daily update in everyday 24:00:00, the code is as follow:

```
Timer nextDayTimer(boost::asio::io_service& ios) {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = {0};
    localtime_r(&now, &tm);
    tm.tm_hour = 0;
    tm.tm_min = 0;
    tm.tm_sec = 0;

    time_t next = mktime(&tm);
    if (next <= now) {
      tm.tm_mday++;
      next = mktime(&tm);
    }

    Timer timer = Timer(new boost::asio::deadline_timer(ios));
    int diff = (int) (diffTime(next, now) * 1000.0);
    timer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(diff));
    return timer;
}
```

Then do daily update when reach the time that the timer expires. and Then call `nextDayTimer` again;

However, I found there are some wrong with it, it occasionally do daily update twice in 24:00:00, what reason would lead to this?

Comment: I supposed if one daily update was done at 23:59:59, then it would do it at 24:00:00 again. However , I do not know what would lead this?

Comment: I'm curious about the `duffTime` function call. Isn't that a typo ?

Comment: @VooDooS it should be `diffTime`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do threads spontaneously awake from wait()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540984/why-do-threads-spontaneously-awake-from-wait)