# wait , notify and notifyall in java?

Tags: java

Please let me know that where i can find the suitable and simple example to use wait(),notify() and notifyall() metods in java.....

Comment: As said by @Vladimir Ivanov, search before asking. Downvoted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple scenario using wait() and notify() in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536692/a-simple-scenario-using-wait-and-notify-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306)

P.S. it is a first link on google. Is it really so hard to find?

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework?  If not, don't use them is my advice.  Use the newer [concurrency libraries](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) which were added in 2004.