# Current thread not owner exception

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime

in my application i am using a code that run a batch file, on executing it i am getting a exception i.e. current thread is not owner.
Here i want to mention that my application is based on eclipse plugin development.
Following is my code, please have a look and find out what is the problem to help me..

```
/*.......any code.........*/
try
{
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String cmd = new String(C:\\abc.bat);
    process = runtime.exec("\"" + cmd + "\"");

    process.wait();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

/***********any code**************/
```

Comment: Note that `process.wait` *almost certainly* does **not** do what you want it to do. You probably want to call [`waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()), which will also solve your problem.

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific.  What are you trying to do?  As @JoachimSauer mentions, `wait()` is almost certainly wrong. What are you trying to do. Note that I removed the eclipse-plugin tag since this question has nothing to do with plugins. If it does, you should edit the question so that the eclipse-plugin relevancy is explicit.

Answer (score 20):

The wait is the method owned by Object, to use the method, you must get the lock of the object, change your code to,

```
try
{
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String cmd = new String(C:\\abc.bat);
    process = runtime.exec("\"" + cmd + "\"");
    synchronized (process){
       try{
          process.wait();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Reasonable answer. Don't know why it was down-voted.  Upvoting, even though it is probably not the correct answer.

Comment: Likely, because that's not what author originally wanted to do. He didn't expect to use synchronization at all.

Comment: you may find this useful as well -> The difference between Synchronized blocks with wait/notify and without them (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7842289/5308115)

Comment: The answer is poorly worded, could be another reason for any down-votes.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you were confused by the `wait()` method name, thinking it may allow you to wait until `exec()` is finished, but really it's not and has completely different purpose.

What I believe you wanted here is to call `Process.waitFor()` method:

```
try {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String cmd = new String(C:\\abc.bat);
    process = runtime.exec("\"" + cmd + "\"");
    process.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

which should do what you may originally expected — to wait until batch execution is finished.

On the other hand, `wait()` method in Java (which comes from `Object.wait()`) is related to multi-threading programming and to Java implementation of the [monitor thread synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) concept. Historically, it was put to the main `Object.java` class, so all classes inherit it and that's what confusion may come from.

In your example it's definitely not the right method to call. And the `IllegalStateMonitor` exception message you're getting:

> current thread is not owner

tries to give you an implicit hint on threads synchronization issue.
Though again, when you're not using multi-threading in your code it may confuse you a lot and doesn't provide any clue what could go wrong, as you not expecting it.

`wait()` method should only be called on the monitor objects, when you're writing code inside of synchronized blocks or methods, e.g.:

```
private final List<Task> tasks = new ArraList<>();

private synchronized void waitForTasks() throws InterruptedException {
    // because 'synchronized' word used on method,
    // here monitor is the whole class, i.e. 'this'
    if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
        wait(); // method is called on the class itself, as it's the monitor object
    }
    doTasks();
}
```

or:

```
private final List<Task> tasks = new ArraList<>();

private void waitForTasks() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (tasks) { // monitor object is set to 'tasks' object
        if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
            tasks.wait();  // method is called on the monitor
        }
        doTasks();
    }
}
```

If you would like to get more information on monitor concept in Java, you can [this nice article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify) on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Use BLocking Queues: Cleanest approach as well as advanced.
Auto generate: start with 1 and keep adding to the other ques in the process.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass clas = new MyClass();
        int max = 20;
        BlockingQueue<Integer> eq = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
        BlockingQueue<Integer> odd = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
        odd.add(1);
        clas.startB(max,clas,odd,eq);
    }
    public void startB(final int max, Object clas,BlockingQueue<Integer> oq,
            BlockingQueue<Integer> eq) {
        Runnable even = () -> {
            int num = 0;
            while(num < max) {
            try {
                num = eq.take();
                if( num%2==0) {
                    System.out.println(num);
                    oq.add(num+1);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
        };
        Runnable odd = () -> {
            int num = 0;
            while(num < max) {
            try {
                if( (num = oq.take())%2==1) {
                    System.out.println(num);
                    eq.add(num+1);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
        };
        new Thread(even).start();
        new Thread(odd).start();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help, use the runnable to create 2 threads responsible for printing even and odd thread and provide the resource to it.

```
public class MyClass {
    volatile int counter = 1;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass clas = new MyClass();
        int max = 20;
        clas.start(max,clas);
    }
    public void start(final int max, Object clas) {
        Runnable even = () -> {
            synchronized(this) {

                while(counter<= max){
                    if(counter % 2 ==0) {
                        System.out.println("even  "+counter);
                        counter++;
                        clas.notify(); 
//no ncecessory to use clas.notify, just notify() / wait() also works

                    }else{
                        try{
                            clas.wait();
                        }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable odd = () -> {
            synchronized(this) {
                while(counter<= max){
                    if(counter % 2 ==1) {
                        System.out.println("odd "+ counter);
                        counter++;
                        clas.notify();

                    }else{
                        try{
                            clas.wait();}catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(even).start();
        new Thread(odd).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32481555)

Answer (score -1):

If you get this error whilst attempting to make the system pause operations, just remember that `wait(1_000)` is not the correct instruction, instead use `Thread.sleep(1_000)`.