# How To Delay Method Return Until File Is Completely Read

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Consider the following code example, in which I removed all error handling code in order to keep it readable:

```
public class MyClass {

  protected Something myAttribute;
  protected boolean busy = true;

  public ReactiveLogger() {
    new Thread(new FileListener()).start();
  }

  private class FileListener implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(LOG_FILE, "rw");
      while (true) {
        final String line = cutFirstLine(raf);
        if (line == null) {
          busy = false;
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        } else {
          busy = true;
          // handeLogMessage changes myAttribute
          handleLogMessage(line);
        }
      }
    }

    // definition of cutFirstLine etc.

  }

  // definition of handleLogMessage etc.

  public Something getSomething() {
    while (busy) {
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    return myAttribute;
  }

}
```

So my class `MyClass` reads a log file in the background (in another thread) and updates an attribute `myAttribute` with every line it reads from the log file. As long as there are any entries in the log file and my attribute is updated, the return of the getter function `getMyAttribute()` should be delayed. As soon as there are no more entries in the log file, `getMyAttribute()` should return `myAttribute`.

Although this code example works as required, it does not seem to be the most elegant solution. It is not clear at all how long the thread should sleep in order to have an optimal result. If one simply removes the call to `Thread.sleep` in the getter function, the program freezes. But if I set the value of the sleep method too high, the execution also takes too long.

How can I achieve the same in a better way? I already had a look at Java multithreading / concurrent programming resources, but nothing (like Java's `synchronized`) seems to fit this situation.

Comment: have a look on `Thread.join()`

Comment: Based on your described goals, I'm not sure I understand why two threads are needed. If your other thread is just blocking until the desired result is found, then don't bother with two threads.

Comment: `Thread.join()` does not help afaik since no thread is expected to end. `getSomething()` can be and is called multiple times. The `run()` method executes forever because at any time, something could be written to the log file again.

Comment: You might want to look into `synchronized`, `wait()` and `notify()`. Be warned: it's complicated.

Comment: @Duncan at any time, stuff can be added to the log file - hence a new thread which observes this file. If the log file is empty, the getter should return the attribute directly. But if the log file is not empty, it should wait until it is completely read and return  the result afterwards.

Comment: @immibis I will. Although a solution without them would be better (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536821/719023))...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I had a look at `synchronized` / `wait()` / `notify()` again. So here is another working and more elegant solution:

```
public class MyClass {

  protected Something myAttribute;
  protected boolean busy = true;
  protected final Object lock = new Object();

  public ReactiveLogger() {
    new Thread(new FileListener()).start();
  }

  private class FileListener implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(LOG_FILE, "rw");
      while (true) {
        final String line = cutFirstLine(raf);
        if (line == null) {
          busy = false;
          synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notifyAll();
          }
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        } else {
          busy = true;
          // handeLogMessage changes myAttribute
          handleLogMessage(line);
        }
      }
    }

    // definition of cutFirstLine etc.

  }

  // definition of handleLogMessage etc.

  public Something getSomething() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      while (busy) {
        lock.wait();
      }
    }
    return myAttribute;
  }

}
```

But there may still be better solutions. Java luminary Josh Bloch strictly advises against using these methods in his book *Effective Java 2nd Edition* (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536821/719023)):

> **Given the difficulty of using `wait` and `notify` correctly, you should use the higher-level concurrency utilities instead** [...] using `wait` and `notify` directly is like programming in "concurrency assembly language", as compared to the higher-level language provided by `java.util.concurrent`. **There is seldom, if ever, reason to use `wait` and `notify` in new code**.