# Custom Array Blocking Queue

Tags: java, blockingqueue

I am trying to implement Blocking Queue functionality but Thread goes in wait state. Not able to figure out what may be going wrong. I tried some of the implementations online, but none are working. Maybe my executors code is wrong. But if I replace `MyBlockingQueue` with `ArrayBlockingQueue` everything works fine.

Below are the two main methods.

```
public synchronized void put(Integer i) throws InterruptedException {

    if (a.size() == capacity) {
        wait();
    }
    a.add(i);
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void take() throws InterruptedException {

    if (a.isEmpty()) {
        wait();
    }
    a.remove(0);
    notifyAll();
}
```

Code:

```
public class App {

    public static MyBlockingQueue q = new MyBlockingQueue(10);

    // public static ArrayBlockingQueue q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);

    public void method1() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            q.put(i);
            System.out.println(q);
        }
    }

    public void method2() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            q.take();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        App a = new App();

        ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        ExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            executor1.submit(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    try {
                        a.method1();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            executor2.submit(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    try {
                        a.method2();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        executor1.shutdown();
        executor2.shutdown();

        executor1.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        executor2.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.DAYS);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The final queue is:");
        System.out.println(App.q);

    }

}

class MyBlockingQueue {

private ArrayList<Integer> a;
    private int capacity;

    public MyBlockingQueue(Integer cap) {
        capacity = cap;
        a = new ArrayList<Integer>(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        for (Integer i : a) {
            output += i.toString() + " ";
        }
        return "[" + output + "]";
    }

    public synchronized void put(Integer i) throws InterruptedException {

        if (a.size() == capacity) {
            wait();
        }
        a.add(i);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void take() throws InterruptedException {

        if (a.isEmpty()) {
            wait();
        }
        a.remove(0);
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use while loops in your put and take methods: `while (a.size() == capacity) {` and `while (a.isEmpty()) {`.

Comment: see [whiles in action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536692/a-simple-scenario-using-wait-and-notify-in-java)

Comment: @MauricePerry even with while loop it's not working perfect. Though better than if. Out of 10 only 1 attempt was success.

Comment: @garg10may one more thing: toString should be synchronized

Comment: @MauricePerry awesome man, I have been trying this for a day, using various if's, whiles, re-entrant locks and what not. Even all online versions were failing, I thought everyone has given the wrong implementation. And this innocuous `toString` was the culprit.

Comment: Don't fix your question to show the working code. It is of no use to anyone unles it exhibits the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the shy looking culprit sitting there in corner,  fixing `if` to `while` was also required.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String output = "";
    for (Integer i : a) {
        output += i.toString() + " ";
    }
    return "[" + output + "]";
}
```

I was adding toString method to solutions and they won't work.

Making it `synchronized` things work fine. Thanks @Maurice for suggesting this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all threads are waiting on the same monitor and will be woken up by notifyAll and run simultaneously.

You can use method `notify` to wake up single thread and make single insert or remove. But `notify()` called inside `put()` can wake up thread waiting to insert on `not full` condition in `put()` method:

```
while (a.size() == capacity) {
        wait(); // many threads waiting
    }
```

And `notify()` called inside `take()` can wake up thread waiting on `not empty` condition:

```
while (a.isEmpty()) {
        wait();
    }
```

Because all threads use one monitor, `notify` can wake up any waiting thread.

So you need two monitors: one for `not full` condition and one for `not empty`.

```
    Object notFull = new Object();
    Object notEmpty = new Object();

    public synchronized void put(Integer i) throws InterruptedException {

        while (a.size() == capacity) {
            notFull.wait(); 
        }
        a.add(i);
        notEmpty.notify(); //wake up one random thread in take() method
    }

    public synchronized void take() throws InterruptedException {

        if (a.isEmpty()) {
            notEmpty.wait();
        }
        a.remove(0);
        notFull.notify(); // wake up one random thread in put() method
    }
```

Now  `notEmpty.notify()` and `notFull.notify()` do not release lock acquired by `synchronized` keyword in `put` or `take` method.

We need to synchronize both methods on the same lock and release or acquire it  based on two conditions: not full and not empty. For this there is [`java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) class:

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and
>   semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized
>   methods and statements, but with extended capabilities.

This class represents a lock with conditions. Its method `[newCondition][2]` creates condition:

> Returns a Condition instance for use with this Lock instance.

[Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) allows to suspend multiple threads by `await()` method and wake up single waiting thread by `signal()` method. It can't be used without ReentrantLock.
When `Condition.await` is called thread releases lock acquired in `ReentrantLock.lock` method. When `Condition.signal` is called, waiting thread acquires `ReentrantLock`.
Final code :

```
/** Main lock guarding all access */
       private final ReentrantLock lock;
       /** Condition for waiting takes */
       private final Condition notEmpty;
       /** Condition for waiting puts */
       private final Condition notFull;

 public void put(Integer i) throws InterruptedException {
          lock.lockInterruptibly();
          try {
                  while (a.size() == capacity)
                      notFull.await();//realease monitor and sleep until notFull.signal is called

             a.add(i);
            notEmpty.signal();// wake up one random thread in take() method
          } finally {
              lock.unlock();
          }
 }

public void take() throws InterruptedException {
          lock.lockInterruptibly();
          try {
                   while (a.isEmpty())
                      notEmpty.await();//realease monitor and sleep until notEmpty.signal is called

                   a.remove(0);
             notFull.signal();// wake up one random thread in put() method
          } finally {
              lock.unlock();
          }       
}
```

`ReentrantLock` ensures that only one thread can execute `put` or `take` methods at the same time. `Condition` allows to suspend and resume threads based on condition.

Answer (score -3):

Methods put and take in `ArrayBlockingQueue` should be synchronized with `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock`.

Example:

```
public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            // your logic 
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```