# wait() and notify() works but I don't understand why

Tags: java, wait, notify

I wrote this for my class solution but I don't understand how it works. I thought when you use wait(), your release the lock to other waiting thread. Then the other thread notify() lets the original thread that issued wait() to resume operation.
What I don't understand is in the printAlphabet() method, I have to put wait() then notify(). Then for printDigits(), I have to put notify() and then wait().

If I just use wait() in the first one, then notify() on the second one. First, printAlphabet() prints a. Then printDigits() prints 1 and will complete the entire loop. And then printAlphabet() resumes BUT then stuck after printing letter b forever.
I even asked my trainer and he couldn't figure it out neither.
Appreciate any help.

```
class Jobs {
    public void printAlphabet() throws Exception {
        char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(alphabet[i] + " ");
//              System.out.println("Waiting to print digit");
                wait();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                notify();

            }

        }
    }

    public void printDigits() throws Exception {
        String[] digits = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26".split(" ");
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(digits[i] + " ");
//              System.out.println("Waiting to print alphabet");
                    notify();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    wait();

                

            }

        }
    }

}

public class Day8Problem31 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Jobs task = new Jobs();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    task.printAlphabet();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    task.printDigits();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/2537117/5493813 or https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's put a few facts

1. `wait` will immediately suspend a thread and release a lock
2. `notify` will resume one blocked thread (by `wait`), however it won't interrupt in any way execution of current thread, it'll continue

In your case thread executing `printDigits` method when calling `notify` will resume thread (blocked by `wait` in `printAlphabet`), however that resumed thread is now trying to aquire a lock on "this", which is being held by 2nd thread (still executing printDigits). Only after 2nd thread releases the lock (by leaving synchronized block or calling wait - which will release lock automatically), the first thread will be able to acquire it and continue